# Event receivers not getting lists

Tags: 2013, 2010, powershell, csom, event-receivers

I am trying list/ or delete an event receiver from my document library. When try to get the event receiver definitions it shows me only DocumentSet event receivers. the custom event receivers(Item Updated) created are not listed. But the custom  event receivers are working, when I  update the items. The event reeivers are attached to list from the elements.xml using the listurl property. 
Please help me with the same.

I have tried to list the event receivers using the Powerhsll, Managed CSOM.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You view/delete event receivers associated with lists/document libraries using this tool. 
http://spm.codeplex.com/